# How do I write code for multiplexer inputs

Tags: arduino

I'm building a testing apparatus using a arduino mega and a multiplexer with 4 inputs, 16 outputs to test each path of a 16 pin ribbon cable. Is there a quick way to build the code for the multiplexer such that it goes through each binary combination once?

So far all I can think of would be to go through each combination with my testing code as a seperate instance, ie, write all my pins low, do test, write pin 1 high, test, pin 1 low pin 2 high, test... etc

Another way would be to have a for loop starting from 0 and have the current iteration of the loop be converted to a 4 digit binary number and then use some array functions to set each multiplexer input pin to it's corresponding binary number, however I only know Matlab well enough to do that, not arduino. Any suggestions on what I should be looking for?

Answer (score 1):

> "How do I write code..."

use an editor, and tap keys.

> "current iteration of the loop be converted to a 4 digit binary"

counts 0 to 15 (0Fh) are just that: all combinations of lowest 4 bits.
There is no need to "convert", and no need for a table lookup (array) - your array index would be identical to the result read from arrray, so use the count (=the index into array) directly.

This assumes that your demultiplexer (4 to 16 is a demux, not a mux - you multiplex many to few (one) and demultiplex few (one) to many) inputs are connected to the lowest 4 bits of output port.